# How to create a scrollable frame within an existing frame in python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I would like to insert a scrollable frame containing `Sample Label 1, Sample Label 2, ...` within a frame in my code below. I have attempted to do this by following [this website](https://blog.teclado.com/tkinter-scrollable-frames/), which is well laid out. However desipite following these instructions and adjusting them to my code, I am still not able to see a scrollbar, even through I am not getting any errors.

I suspect that it might be the way I `pack` the scrollbar which makes it disappear from the main window. So have tried using `place` with the `in_` option in order to place it relative to the canvas however this returns an error. Thanks for your help in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class MyGUI(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # define variables
        GRID = 25
        X = GRID*20
        Y = GRID*15

        # create spinbox
        self.Label = tk.Label(text='Number of Shafts')
        self.Label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.Spinbox = tk.Spinbox(from_=0, to=10, width=3)
        self.Spinbox.grid(row=0, column=1)

        # create scrollable frame
        self.Table = tk.Canvas(height=100, width=150, background='white',
                               highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground='black')
        self.Table.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.Scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.Table.yview)
        self.Scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')

        self.Table.configure(yscrollcommand=self.Scrollbar.set)
        self.Table.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.Table.configure(scrollregion=self.Table.bbox('all')))

        self.Scrollable_Frame = ttk.Frame(self.Table)
        self.Table.create_window((0, 0), window=self.Scrollable_Frame, anchor="nw")

        self.Table.configure(yscrollcommand=self.Scrollbar.set)

        for i in range(50):
            ttk.Label(self.Scrollable_Frame, text=("Sample label %d" % i)).pack()

        # create canvas
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(width=X+1, height=Y+1, background='white',
                                highlightthickness=1, highlightbackground='black')
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=2)

        # create grid
        for i in range(0, Y, GRID):
            self.canvas.create_line(0, i, X, i, fill='gray')
        for i in range(0, X, GRID):
            self.canvas.create_line(i, 0, i, Y, fill='gray')

        # create rectangle
        x0 = GRID*3
        y0 = GRID*4
        wid = GRID
        hei = GRID
        self.create_shaft(x0, y0, wid, hei)

        # add bindings to clicks
        self._drag_data = {"x": 0, "y": 0, "item": None}
        self.canvas.tag_bind('inertia', "<ButtonPress-1>", self.drag_start)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('inertia', "<ButtonRelease-1>", self.drag_stop)
        self.canvas.tag_bind('inertia', "<B1-Motion>",
                             lambda event, grid_x=GRID, grid_y=GRID: self.drag(event, grid_x, grid_y))

    def create_shaft(self, x0, y0, wid, hei):
        """Create shaft drawing"""
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x0+wid, y0+hei, fill='gray', tags=('inertia',))

    def drag_start(self, event):
        """Beginning drag of an object"""
        # record the item and its location
        self._drag_data["item"] = self.canvas.find_closest(event.x, event.y)[0]
        self._drag_data["x"] = event.x
        self._drag_data["y"] = event.y

    def drag_stop(self, event):
        """End drag of an object"""
        # reset the drag information
        self._drag_data["item"] = None
        self._drag_data["x"] = 0
        self._drag_data["y"] = 0

    def drag(self, event, grid_x, grid_y):
        """Handle dragging of an object"""
        # compute how much the mouse has moved
        delta_x = round((event.x - self._drag_data["x"])/grid_x)*grid_x
        delta_y = round((event.y - self._drag_data["y"])/grid_y)*grid_y
        # move the object the appropriate amount
        self.canvas.move(self._drag_data["item"], delta_x, delta_y)
        # record the new position
        self._drag_data["x"] += delta_x
        self._drag_data["y"] += delta_y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tk.Tk()
    app.title('hi')
    MyGUI(app).place()

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you're wanting to scroll a vertical stack of widgets, it is much easier to use a text widget than it is to use a canvas with an embedded frame.

Comment: I suggest creating a class that implements the scrolling. That way your code will look much cleaner.

Comment: My plan is to include a text and an edit field within that scrollable frame. So I should create a scrollable text widget and drop in there my text and edit fields?

Comment: @kostas1335 The `tkinter.Text` widget does allow you to insert other widgets as if they were single characters. Maybe you could add a frame to a `tkinter.Text`: `Text.window_create(1.0, window=your_frame_widget)`.

Comment: examples with [scrolled frames and canvas](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/scrolled-frame-canvas)